# Node.js: Double '/' characters are loaded from .env file

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use `.env` file in my Node.js backend.
It has `Firebase` credentials as the environment variables.

```
privateKey=-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvwIBADANBgkqhk
```

But when I run the Node.js codes, `process.env.privateKey` is `privateKey: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\nMIIEvwIBADANBgkqh`.
Finally double `'\'` characters are loaded.
A single '\' character should be loaded.
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: It might be an idea to post your source code here and how you know that is the value in Node.

Comment: It is the same when I set it to the Heroku env variable

Comment: Hmmm how about 'console.log()' ?

Comment: Like this: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\nMIIE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node isn't doing that. It's a side-effect of the REPL to avoid \n being interpreted as a newline. You could use

```
let private_key = process.env.privateKey.replace(/\\n/g, '\n');
console.log(private_key);
```

to see it without the extra slash.

Comment: How can I avoid it?

Comment: @Ilya_Shamshudinov You can't "avoid" it but I've updated my answer with some sample code that might help.